# html template without using php or rails ect

Tags: html, templates, compilation, haml, partials

I am looking for a way to code html templates without using any "backend" languages like php or ruby/rails.

using JS could work but i have issues with my current javascript when i add nodes after the DOM is loaded.

the solution that would be ideal is if there is a preprocessor of some kind that i can compile into finished html.. something similar to SCSS but for html

just so i'm clear and i have enough content for stackoverflow..

i want partial.folders content to compile into index.html

```
partial.folder
  menu.html
  root.html
  footer.html
|
|
V
index.html
```

Answer (score 1):

Depends on "when" you want to parse the templates.

1) At runtime: you could try to use https://github.com/janl/mustache.js - javascript Logic-less templates

2) At build time: I would suggest using nodejs+Grunt (http://gruntjs.com/) + grunt-preprocess (grunt plugin)

Comment: mustache.js is more along the lines of what i'm looking for. do you know if mustache.js will let me use regular jQuery statements like `$("nav").click(function(){})` even though the `<nav>...</nav>` is added dynamically?

Comment: @JamesDHarrington Just ensure that the jQuery statements are run after mustache.js finished parsing. See the examples in mustache.js github page; it uses jQuery to replace content of an element with parsed template.

Comment: @SAnDAnGE could you maybe elaborate a bit, or maybe there are some more links to read on how exactly to achieve such a task with a taskrunner like grunt or maybe a build tool like gobble? I am also searching for a simple way to automatically compile simple HTML files into one big index.html (at build time; without using PHP or the like).

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer to my own question. a program called codekit worked exactly how i wanted it to. thanks for the help! http://incident57.com/codekit/